# truncate table. Error Msg = sqlcode -668 sqlerrmc=7

Tags: db2, dbeaver

I am trying to run this DB2 query on DBEAVER:

`TRUNCATE table departments immediate`

but I got this error:

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, SQLERRMC=7;DB2INST1.DEPARTMENTS, DRIVER=4.19.49`

(it is happening just when I run it on DBEVAER (external channel) on local it's run well.

help someone?

Comment: ORA-02000 is not a Db2 error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sqlcode -668 with sqlerrmc=7  (this 7 is the "reason code") means:

> SQL0668N  Operation not allowed for reason code "" on
> table
> "".

and the reason code 7 means:

> The table is in the reorg pending state. This can occur after     an
> ALTER TABLE statement containing a REORG-recommended   operation.

If your userid has the correct permissions, then try:

```
reorg table db2inst1.departments
```

if you have command-line access to Db2, or from jdbc application like DBeaver `call admin_cmd ('reorg table db2inst1.departments')`.

But the reorg will fail if your account lacks permissions, or if the syntax is not allowed on your Db2-server version, and in that case you must ask a DBA to do the work for you, or a become user `db2inst1` and run the reorg.

When the reorg completes without errors, retry the truncate table.

Comment: Is there a query that "cancel" the reorg table?
it seems that it's stuck on the reorg table query (that I run previous), and cant complete the operation of truncate because of it.

Comment: It's not possible to take a table out of reorg-pending state with online (inplace) reorg. Offline (classic) reorg must be used. `call admin_cmd ('reorg table db2inst1.departments')`.

Comment: What about `CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE db2inst1.departments INPLACE ALLOW READ ACCESS START');`