# DB2, Error setting default catalog/schema for new connection

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, db2, dbeaver

i use IBM DB2 clp and dbeaver. my username is A_sq.k in system. this problem is persisting when inserting values on to tables. saying SQL Error [57007]: Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table "A_SQ.K.SHOPPING_CART".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57007, DRIVER=4.33.31. Even though the insertion it self had no problems.
this the actual error detail reason i am asking for:
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "." was found following "A_SQ".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.33.31

i have been trying to make a fix through Chatgpt but i might need the community help. i have been struggling with this error in DBeaver a Database IDE. i want to run my work in the database but it seems i am having problems schema naming from what i feel. so i want to know how to change the name of the schema. i tried RENAME function in clp but i got this error.
db2 => RENAME USER A_SQ.K TO ANAS_KHAN
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "A_SQ.K TO ANAS_KHAN" was found following
"RENAME USER ".  Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601
the reason i am stuck with this IDE is because my assignment must be in this IDE only.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70288355/truncate-table-error-msg-sqlcode-668-sqlerrmc-7/70289898#70289898) how you can handle code -668

Comment: Your user name contains a dot you must enclose it between double quotes so that DB2 doesn't see it as a part of the syntax, and double quotes will make it case sensitive. Btw even if you manage to rename the schema I think DB2 could create another one with the user name when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to check [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5) instead of trying to guess commands that might work.

You cannot rename a Db2 user, because users are not defined by the database; they are the operating system users.

You cannot rename a schema either (which defaults to your authorisation/user name if you don't specify it explicitly).

As mentioned in the comment, if your user ID contains special characters, so will your default schema name, and you should enclose the name in double quotes

```sql
SELECT whatever FROM "A_SQ.K".SHOPPING_CART ...
```